# Forward requested subdomain/host from GCP Load Balancer to Cloud Run

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, gcp-load-balancer

I have an Express app used by several companies. Each company has its own subdomain to call the app api, such as `company1.mydomain.com`, `company2.mydomain.com`. In Express we read the value of the subdomain to determine the custom operation that we have to do for that company.

We are moving this app to GCP using Cloud Run with a GCP Load Balancer, setting all subdomains on the latter. We are now trying to read the subdomain but it contains the subdomain value of the Cloud Run URL (`xxxxx.a.run.app`). We are trying to figure out how to get the subdomain the user is requesting (the one configured in the Load Balancer) but that value doesn't seem to be forwarded to Cloud RUN.

Are there any settings that we are missing or something that help us to read the subdomain value  from Cloud Run?

PD: We tried using Load Balancer's Custom Header but there is no option related to subdomain value

PD2: We also tried checking the other headers (including the `X-Somethingxx` GCP headers) and found nothing

Comment: Did you inspect the headers? Do you have the `x-forwarded-host` header value?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere No, I don't have it. The `x-` Headers that I can see are: `x-cloud-trace-context`, `x-forwarded-for`, `x-forwarded-proto` and `x-request-id`. None of them contains the subdomain

Comment: Do you use HTTPS protocol on your load balancer?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes. We have an HTTPS LB and HTTP LB redirecting to HTTPS.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. It's based on [a recent article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-load-balancing-go-beyond-your-own-project-adfa1c8b001d) that I wrote.

The solution is:

- Create a HTTPS load balancer
- Define an internet NEG that call run.app
- In the backend, use this NEG and add custom header host, with the value of the fully qualified URL of your Cloud Run service `xxxxx.a.run.app` (like described in my article)
- Add another custom header (this one that you want, for example `x-forwarded-host`) with the value `{tls_sni_hostname}`

Comment: I already did something similar using the `{tls_sni_hostname}` custom header. The problem with this value is that it is set in the handshake process and it keeps the same value until you need a new handshake for another certificate/url. So like I said in the original post, several companies and their customers use our api (`company1.mydomain.com` `company2.mydomain.com`).All subdomains use the same Certificate, so if a customer request `company1.mydomain.com` the SNI is set to that URL and if then the same customer call `company2.mydomain.com` the SNI will remain `company1.mydomain.com`

Comment: That is because a new handshake is not required. This can be fixed using different certificates for each domain, but  for us that is not feasible.

That's what I understand about SNI, but I may be completely wrong

Comment: I guess you use a wildcard certificate, correct?

Comment: Yes, we use a wildcard certificate