# How to integrate Cloud Armor with Firebase host domain

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

We have hosted our static content in Firebase Hosting. I want to use Cloud Armor in front of it. So that I would be able to restrict IP accessing the domain. Could anyone share any info related to this scenario. If there is any alternative solution is available for IP restriction is fine as well.

I tried to utilize Internet network endpoint group with GCP app load balancer. I added the firebase domain url as the FQDN for endpoint. Attached that backend to the LB. I have created SSL certificate and attached to a new domain I created. And mapped the LB IP to the new domain. But now I am getting SITE NOT FOUND screen with the content as below

```
Site Not Found
Why am I seeing this?

There are a few potential reasons:

    You haven't deployed an app yet.
    You may have deployed an empty directory.
    This is a custom domain, but we haven't finished setting it up yet.

How can I deploy my first app?

Refer to our hosting documentation to get started.
```

Comment: Please dont use screenshots - post the actual error message in text https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Also - this is probably off-topic for StackOverflow. You may get a better response on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have replaced the error content with the screenshot. I could see better response for Firebase and Cloud Armor related questions on Stack overflow. So let me keep it here for now. I'll also try to use serverfault.com

Comment: I am not sure, but the problem might be caused by the HTTP Host header having the wrong hostname. Try setting the Host header: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/custom-headers to be the Firebase URL. Also see this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66071092/8016720